# System-wide known-hosts file?

Tags: ubuntu, git, openssh, github

I am trying to do a github-*git pull* from a php script as a www-data user and i am getting "Host key verification failed.". My main user has the host key registered, but my www-data does not as it doesn't even have access to the ~/.ssh directory.

Is there still a system-wide known-hosts file under Ubuntu 18.04? I suppose it would not be secure to give the www-data user access to my *~/.ssh*-directory?

Comment: Consider using https instead of ssh for the git pull?

Comment: `sudo -sH -u www-data` and then test it from a shell

Comment: @GMaster The problem with that is, that i need a way to pull without having to enter any credentials.

Answer (score 1):

As @GMaster suggested, using HTTPS instead of SSH for an automated pull seems the most sensible choice. But, if you really require using ssh protocol (why?), you have a few options to deal with `known_hosts` and credentials:

- Create the `~/.ssh` tree, including a pre-populated `known_hosts`, at `www-data`'s home directory (in my system it's `/var/www`, but check yours in `/etc/passwd`). You can create the file yourself by connecting and verifying the host key manually. Just make sure such files and dirs have the proper permissions (usually 0700/0600) and ownership.
- Have this file elsewhere (with proper permissions), and point to it using `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/known_hosts`
- For both above approaches, fiddle with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking` various options and `-o UpdateHostKeys` to balance between security and convenience.
- As a last resort, you can completely disable host key validation for www-data, either in `/var/www/.ssh/config` or with command-line options `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`. Just be aware of the serious security implication this implies.

And, reinforcing what you already suspected: under no circumstances give www-data (or any other) user access to your `~/.ssh`. Remember your *private* keys are there too!

Comment: *Add options to disable host key validation...*  I'd think connecting manually while logged in as `www-data` and actually verifying the host key would be better.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: true, I'll add a security remark in the answer. The other 2 (better) options I offered also involves a manual verification to create a pre-populated `known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is indeed a system-wide known hosts file, which is by default `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`.  You can run `man ssh_config` and search for `GlobalKnownHostsFile` to see the default on your system.  You can also change the value of this option as normal (with `-o`) if you  like.